# Python 3.4 - reading data from a webpage

Tags: python, url, python-3.x, html

I'm currently trying to learn how to read from a webpage, and have tried the following:

```
>>>import urllib.request
>>>page = urllib.request.urlopen("http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/", data = None)
>>>contents = page.read()
>>>lines = contents.split('\n')
```

This gives the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#4>", line 1, in <module>
    lines = contents.split('\n')
TypeError: Type str doesn't support the buffer API
```

Now I assumed that reading from a URL would be pretty similar from reading for a text file, and that the contents of `contents` would be of type `str`. Is this not that case?

When I try `>>> contents` I can see that the contents of `contents` is just the HTML document, so why doesn't `.split('\n') work? How can I make it work?

Please note that I'm splitting at the newline characters so I can print the webpage line by line.

Following the same train of thought, I then tried `contents.readlines()` which gave this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#8>", line 1, in <module>
    contents.readlines()
AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'readlines'
```

Is the webpage stored in some object called 'bytes'?

Can someone explain to me what is happening here? And how to read the webpage properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to wrap it with an `io.TextIOWrapper()` object and encode your file (`utf-8` is a universal you can change it to proper encoding too):

```
import urllib.request
import io
u = urllib.request.urlopen("http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/", data = None)
f = io.TextIOWrapper(u,encoding='utf-8')
text = f.read()
```

Answer (score 1):

Decode the bytes object to produce a string:

```
lines = contents.decode(encoding="UTF-8").split("/n")
```

Answer (score 0):

The return type of the `read()` method is of type `bytes`. You need to properly decode it to a string before you can use a string method like `split`. Assuming it is UTF-8 you can use:

```
s = contents.decode('utf-8')
lines = s.split('\n')
```

As a general solution you should check the character encoding the server provides in the response to your request and use that.